# ASP.NET MVC - Foreign Key as Primary Key?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, data-annotations

Is it possible to have a Foreign Key as the Primary Key?
If so, can someone help me with my code?

```
<Key()>
Public Property AssignmentID() As Integer
<ForeignKey("AssignmentID")>
Public Overridable Property Assignment As Assignment

Public Overridable Property User As User
```

For the code above I get an error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model
>   generation:
>
> System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in
>   Role 'AssignmentLocks_Assignment_Source' in relationship
>   'AssignmentLocks_Assignment'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the
>   key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent
>   Role must be �1�.

I'm trying to create a table which has one (or none) record per assignment.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to create a table which has one (or none) record per assignment then how do you have AssignmentID unique in that table for multiple rows? You should create a table with unique AssignmetnID and then AssignmetnRecordID for those multiple records per assignment.

Example code is in C# as I am more familiar with C# syntax.

you should be creating a datamodel something like this,

```
public class xyz
{
    public int AssignmentID { get; set; }

    // Some other properties

    [ForeignKey("AssignmetnRecordID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Assignment> AssignmentRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to just add the assignment as a property (sorry C# syntax):

```
public class Xyz
{
    public int XyzID { get; set; }

    public int AssignmentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignmentId")]
    public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; set; }
}

public class Assignment
{
    public int AssignmentID { get; set; }

}
```

XyzID and AssignmentID would probably not be the same, but it allows for only 0 or 1 assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  One common example would be a table to implement a many-to-many relationship between two tables.  For example Roles and User would have a many-to-many relationship and the combination of the two IDs would make a good primary key.
The trick is the DatabaseGenerate attribute which allow you t tell EF that you will generate the value for the key, not the database as is the case for identity int fields.

```
public class RoleUsers
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int          RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role   { get; set; }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
}
```

However, in your case, you want a 0 or 1 relationship so you should

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? AssignmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Assignment Assignment { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

THe nullable int (int?) allows the 0 or one relationship and the generated column is nullable.  If it is just int, then the column is not nullable and there must be an associated Assignement.